# Why can't I create a folder in %CATALINA_TMPDIR%?

Tags: java, tomcat, java-io, catalina

This is the weirdest thing ever. I'm working on an app that I run using Tomcat though IntelliJ IDE. Part of this app creates a folder in the configured `%CATALINA_TMPDIR%`. For some reason no matter where I point `%CATALINA_TMPDIR%` to java can't create a folder there, but it can create a folder everywhere else.

For example, If 
`CATALINA_TMPDIR=C:\Users\dallend\.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\Unnamed_datasite_7\temp` then my app can't create a folder there, but can create it in `C:\Temp`, a folder I created.

Then if I change to `CATALINA_TMPDIR=C:\Temp`, the app won't be able to create a directory there but will be able to create one at `C:\SomewhereElse`.

From debugging through things it appears that java.io.File tries to create the directory but that the `WinNTFileSystem.public native boolean createDirectory()` method can't successfully create it.

Why might this happen? Could there be something I need to tweak with IntelliJ, or Java, or my OS? Has anyone encountered this before?

**EDIT:** I've tried running Tomcat stand-alone, and the problem persists.

Comment: Do you get any errors when you try to create the directory?

Comment: From your question it is unclear whether the app can create a directory _anywhere_.  Can it?  This sounds like you might have a permission issue.  Try running Tomcat in administrator mode.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I tried to explain in my question that my app can create folders other places, just not wherever happens to be configured as CATALINA_TMPDIR. For example, If CATALINA_TMPDIR=C:\Temp, then my app won't be able to create folders in C:\Temp but will be able to create folders in C:\SomewhereElse

Comment: @user2341963, I don't get any errors. WinNTFileSystem.public native boolean createDirectory() returns false rather than throwing an exception.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, How do I run tomcat in administrator mode?

Comment: Assuming you are launching Tomcat from a command prompt, you need to open a command prompt in admin mode.  Right click the command prompt icon and choose run as administrator.  Then let Tomcat deploy your WAR as usual.  Maybe this will work.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, it appears that my command prompt runs as Administrator by default. I.e. Every window I open with it is titled "Administrator: Command Prompt"

Comment: How are you assiging the `CATALINA_TMPDIR` environment variable?  I believe you may have given it a value which appears correct, but which is not a valid formatted path.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, when running through intelliJ CATALINA_TMPDIR is configured via the tomcat run configuration. When running from the command line, CATALINA_TMPDIR is set via an environmental variable. In both cases it is set to C:\Temp. I'm sure this folder exists since I created it manually.

Comment: What does `echo %CATALINA_TMPDIR%` show?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, It shows C:\Temp. I'm sure that the path is correct and is being passed in correctly since tomcat logs out what value it's using for CATALINA_TMPDIR when it starts up.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use forward slashes in your directory names. I've pulled out a lot of hair with backslashes actually escaping a path, e.g. `C:\temp` pointing to `C:<tab>emp`. I've completely given up on using backslashes even on Windows: Java will translate forward slashes just fine: `C:/temp/`